# Exception when creating migrations for Entity FrameworkCore 2.0 in Xamarin Forms App (.NET Standard 2.0)

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-migrations

I have been trying to create an initial migration within my .NET Standard 2.0 cross-plattform Xamarin project.
I have installed the console tools following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

I've enabled cross-framework targeting for my shared library (it targets .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core App 2.0) and set this project as the Starting Project.

The problem is when executing `Add-Migration Initial` or `Get-DbContext` I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init();
>   prior to using it.    at Xamarin.Forms.Device.get_PlatformServices()
>   at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Initialize()    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get[T](DependencyFetchTarget
>   fetchTarget)    at
>   ParkingApp.Models.ParkingDbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   optionsBuilder) in D:\LetzFlow\Projekte\Parking
>   App\Source\ParkingApp\ParkingApp\ParkingApp\Models\ParkingDbContext.cs:line
>   33    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_DatabaseCreator()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
>   at ParkingApp.Models.ParkingDbContext..ctor() in
>   D:\LetzFlow\Projekte\Parking
>   App\Source\ParkingApp\ParkingApp\ParkingApp\Models\ParkingDbContext.cs:line
>   30

The exception comes from the `OnConfiguring()` method in my `Context`
because I'm using the `DependencyService` which needs `Xamarin.Forms`
to be initialized.

So I guess my solution would be to create some kind of `#IF TARGET_FRAMEWORK == .NET_CORE_2` and so on to make sure no `Xamarin.Forms` code is called while using the migration console tools.

But how would I do that? Or do I need to copy paste the code in every time I need to create a migration?